# How to count numbers in a list via certain rules?

Tags: python, string

Just to say I have a str and a list of strs and I want to count how many strs in the list that is contained in a str. Is there an elegant way to do that?

For example,

```
l = {"foo", "bar", "what"}
str = "foobar"
```

The output will be 2.

My way to do this for now is iterate the list and see whether str.contains(str_in_list)

Comment: You don't have a list, that's a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum(s in my_string for s in l)`

Comment: You can omit the list comprehension and directly use the generator expression within it. E.g. leave out the brackets. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example,

```
l = ["foo", "bar", "what"]
st = "foobar"

count = 0
for _string in l:
    if _string in st:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: style-nitpick: I wouldn't use `each_string` as your iterator variable name - note that your inner condition now gives the wrong impression `if each_string in st`, wheraes it's really "if string in st"

Answer (score 1):

Use count:

```
l = {"foo", "bar", "what"}
str = "foobar"
c = [item in str for item in l].count(True)
```

In my opinion this is the most readable version. `item in str` means check if `item` is a substring of `str`. `for item in l` means that it should iterate through each list item in `l` (btw convention is not to use lowercase L for a variable name, as it looks nearly identical to the numeral 1 in many fonts). Finally `.count(True)` returns the number of times `True` exists in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution

```
count = sum(item in str for item in l)
```

Comment: or better yet, just `sum(item in str for item in l)`

Comment: Yep. I always keep forgetting that `True`is a special version of `1`.