# How to select part of a string?

Tags: python, string, list, count, pygal

I'm trying to compare the Gen-Eds needed to graduate at various colleges I'm considering. I want to specifically count anything that contains a key term(ex: ENG), but I can only get it to work for the whole string.

My current code looks like this

```
lis_UofM= ['LINGUS','MATH','NatSCI','LINGUS', 'ART', 'SocSCI']
lis_IIT=['MATH','NatSCI','ENG','MATH','PhysSCI','CompSCI']
lis_UCSD=['ENG','MATH','NatSCI','ENG','SocSCI','ART']

UofM_ENG=lis_UofM.count('ENG')+lis_UofM.count('LINGUS')
IIT_ENG=lis_IIT.count('ENG')
UCSD_ENG=lis_UCSD.count('ENG')

chart=pygal.StackedBar()
chart.add('UofM-Twin Cities',[UofM_MATH,UofM_ENG])
chart.add('IIT',[IIT_MATH, IIT_ENG])
chart.add('UCSD',[UCSD_MATH,UCSD_ENG])
chart.render()
```

I would like to count classes like `'ENG103'` and `'ENG 202'` or count all classes containing `'SCI'` without making separate count functions for each of them. Is that possible?

Comment: i would do like `IIT_ENG=len([x for x in lis_IIT if 'ENG' in x])`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like this

```
sum('ENG' in s for s in lis_IIT)
```

This other post has some additional info and techniques

[Count occurrences of a substring in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738789/count-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: You would have to post your updated code for me to take a look

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @MakaylaLawrence if this response answers your question could you mark it as such to help others looking for an answer in the future.